# Выбор последней (по времени добавления) записи в таблице

Tags: mysql

Можно ли выбрать последнюю (по времени добавления в таблицу) запись в таблице, если поля времени добавления записи в нет?

Например, у меня есть таблица `sms_map` с двумя полями - `sms_in_id` и `sms_out_id`, и следующий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `sms_map`
WHERE `sms_out_id` = 3251;
```

возвращает такой результат:

> 2521 3251
>
> 3221 3251
>
> 3216 3251

Я бы хотела получить последнюю запись. Запрос с сортировкой мне не подходит, так как запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `sms_map`
WHERE `sms_out_id` = 3251 
ORDER BY `sms_in_id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

возвращает последнюю запись по значению поля, а не по по времени добавления записи в таблицу.

Comment: Без ORDER BY никакой порядок вывода результатов SELECT'а не гарантирован и более того, может отличаться от запуска к запуску. Соответственно, если в таблице нет никаких данных, на основании которых можно получить желаемую сортировку, то ответ на вопрос - нет..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. Это невозможно. Вам нужно завести либо поле "время добавления" либо автоинкрементное поле

Answer (score 1):

Я приняла ответ выше, и я понимаю, что это ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ответ. Но вдруг у кого-нибудь будет такая же ситуация, как у меня, когда таблица уже создана, а ни поля "время добавления", ни автоинкрементного поля в таблице нет... И нужно выбрать  последнюю по времени добавления в таблицу запись хотя бы с наибольшей вероятностью (так как обычно строки возвращаются в том же порядке, что и вставлялись, но только до тех пор, пока к таблице не будет применена операция обновления или удаления).

Так что если операций обновления или удаления не было, то вероятность правильного результат будет высокой. В этом случае может помочь следующее:

```
SET @num = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sms_map` WHERE `sms_out_id` = 3251);
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM (SELECT * FROM `sms_map` WHERE `sms_out_id` = 3251) t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) d WHERE rank =  @num;
```